# Tables should never be used for layout, but I couldn't find a better way

Tags: php

So I'm generating an html table through my php to arrange my content.
Unfortunately, the code is ugly, hard to work with, and as we all know, tables should NEVER EVER be used for layout.

The problem is that based on the content I wanted to put on my page from my database, I couldn't figure out any other option.

I would prefer to use divs or lists here, but I can't figure out how best to do it. If the content wasn't dynamic, it'd be easy, but it's a little more complicated than that.

Here's my php:

```
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM titles';
    $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $entries_per_row = 2;

    $i = 1;
    $j = 1;
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {           
        echo "<table class=\"category_list\">\r\n".
            "<tr>\r\n".
            "<td colspan=\"".$entries_per_row."\">\r\n".
            "<a id=\"sh".$i."\" href=\"#\" class=\"showhide\">-</a>&nbsp;<span class=\"title\">".$row['TitleName']."</span>\r\n".
            "</td>\r\n".
            "</tr>\r\n";

        $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE TitleID = '.$row['TitleID'];
        $rows2 = array();
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql2) as $row2) {
            $rows2[] = $row2;
        }

        $rows2 = array_chunk($rows2, $entries_per_row);

        foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
            echo "<tr id=\"".$i."tr".$j."\">\r\n";

            foreach($row2 as $element) {
                if ($element['CategoryName'] != '' && $element['CategorySummary'] != '') {
                    echo "<td class=\"cat\">\r\n".
                        "<a class=\"cat_title\" href=\"display.php?cat=".$element['CategoryName']."&page=1\">".$element['CategoryName']."</a><br />\r\n".
                        "<span class=\"cat_sum\">".$element['CategorySummary']."</span>\r\n".
                        "</td>\r\n";
                }
            }
            $j = $j + 1;
            echo "</tr>\r\n";
        }

        $i = $i + 1;
        echo "</table>\r\n";
    }
?>
```

Here's the HTML that it outputs (indenting included):

```
<table class="category_list">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a id="sh1" href="#" class="showhide">-</a>&nbsp;<span class="title">Test Title 1</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1tr1">
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 1&page=1">Test Category 1</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 2&page=1">Test Category 2</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1tr2">
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 3&page=1">Test Category 3</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="category_list">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a id="sh2" href="#" class="showhide">-</a>&nbsp;<span class="title">Test Title 2</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2tr3">
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 4&page=1">Test Category 4</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 5&page=1">Test Category 5</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2tr4">
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 6&page=1">Test Category 6</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="category_list">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a id="sh3" href="#" class="showhide">-</a>&nbsp;<span class="title">Test Title 3</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3tr5">
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 7&page=1">Test Category 7</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 8&page=1">Test Category 8</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3tr6">
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 9&page=1">Test Category 9</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cat">
            <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 10&page=1">Test Category 10</a><br />
            <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If anyone can suggest some php code that'll arrange this correctly using divs or lists, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You have tabular data, so I see nothing wrong with using a HTML table.

Comment: Advise that comes wrapped in "never" or "always" isn't actually good advise. Never.

Comment: This isn't really tabular data... its 3 separate lists. Also, he is using 3 separate tables.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the differences between the elements you have here. Do you have 3 main categories, with subcategories? Why do some categories appear 1 to a table row, and others 2 to a table row?

Comment: @MrGlass It goes Title (Test Title 1) which has Category children (Test Category 1, 2, 3, etc). Each Title's categories should be laid out in rows of 2. If there's an odd number of rows in the resultset, it should create a new row with just 1 item in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just refactor your HTML code with a very simple technique if you want to use divs instead. Just port every table tag into a div and give it it's class. If you run across a table tag you think it does not belongs to the "table", give it another class:

From:

```
<table class="category_list">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a id="sh1" href="#" class="showhide">-</a>&nbsp;<span class="title">Test Title 1</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="1tr1">
    <td class="cat">
        <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 1&page=1">Test Category 1</a><br />
        <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cat">
        <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 2&page=1">Test Category 2</a><br />
        <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

To:

```
<div class="table category_list">
<div class="showhide-container">
    <a id="sh1" href="#" class="showhide">-</a>&nbsp;<span class="title">Test Title 1</span>
</div>
<div class="table-tr" id="1tr1">
    <div class="table-td cat">
        <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 1&page=1">Test Category 1</a><br />
        <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-td cat">
        <a class="cat_title" href="display.php?cat=Test Category 2&page=1">Test Category 2</a><br />
        <span class="cat_sum">This is a test category. It will be deleted soon.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This refactoring is quite easy to do and you only need to change some of the strings in your output routine, the overall routine stays merely the same.

Answer (score 1):

First off, making complicated layouts like this becomes much easier when you use a template engine. I recommend [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), it will save you a lot of time building template.

That said, its always good to know how to do stuff on your own. So heres what I would do:

First, I would grab a list of all the main categories (in this case, the 3 categories at the top of your table. You can then make a loop that loads a list of child categories and outputs the div/table/ul for that category.

Next, I would build the container for the category. I probably would make a div, an h3 with the category title, and then a UL with all the child categories. You could easily so similar with just a UL, but having the main categories listed as headers is better for accessibility (screen reader users often use headers as an index for the page content, and can skip directly to the section under a given header).

After that, you need to make 2 different LI templates. One will be for when you have a row of 2 items, and a second for when you only have 1 left. When you are looping through your results, you can use an if/else to figure out if there is only 1 item left, and output the LI style needed.